Tomcat Connection pool to Forge MySQL
My Database happens to be hosted on https://forge.laravel.com/ They appear to be using MySQL8 if that makes a difference. I'm writing a Tomcat application from which I would like to connect to this Database using a connection pool, however I'm having trouble figuring out what the connection string (i.e. URL) should be.
Currently the Tomcat is running on my desktop. As a side note, I have been able to connect MySQL Workbench to this database.
199.199.199.199 - Is the placeholder for the server address
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="Bircas" path="/Bircas" reloadable="false" crossContext="true">
    
       <!-- Resource defines a JNDI Datasource to be used in the Realm Definition -->
       <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                  driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                  url="jdbc:mysql+ssh://forge@199.199.199.199/forge@127.0.0.1/forge?name=v2&amp;usePrivateKey=true;"
                  username="forge" password="veryverysecret"
                  maxTotal="-1"
                  maxIdle="10"
                  maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
    
       <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/mysql"
       userTable="users" userNameCol="email" userCredCol="password"
       userRoleTable="users" roleNameCol="role"/>

</Context>

The error that I receive is:
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 
'jdbc:mysql+ssh://forge@199.199.199.199/forge@127.0.0.1/forge?name=v2&usePrivateKey=true;'

Any ideas of what might be wrong are welcome.
Hope I included all pertinent info.
